# How do I check what my domain name's current nameservers are?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain, ip, nameserver

I switched nameservers last night, but I don't know if it has fully made the switch yet.

I want to ping my domain name and see what nameservers it is set as...

Answer (score 6):

There are two primary ways to do this, neither of which involves the `ping` tool.:

1. Look at the `whois` data.
   This will typically include a section titled something like "Domains servers in listed order", which lists your nameservers.
2. `dig -t NS mydomain.com`
   This will report the NS records that your local nameserver gets when it tries to resolve `mydomain.com`.

Ideally these two lists should match exactly.  If you recently switched name servers it may take some time before `dig` results agree with the `whois` data (however long it takes the NS records to expire from the caches along the way).